# Is there a robust way to test for a corrupted blockchain?

Tags: blockchain, bitcoind

While running `bitcoind` I once had the blockchain get corrupted and it manifested as a non-obvious error message which unfortunately I can't remember. I would like to know if there is a robust way to check that the blockchain has been corrupted, preferably using a standard tool such as `bitcoin-cli`.

I'd prefer to err on the side of false positives (it's not corrupt but the test says it is corrupt) if necessary.

Comment: Reindexing with `bitcoind -reindex` should detect any corruption, but takes a long time.  In principle it should be sufficient to compute the hashes of all the blocks in the `blk*.dat` files and check that they all link together in a chain.

Comment: By corrupted blockchain, do you mean that literally the blocks on disk are corrupted (uncommon) or that Bitcoin Core's database was in an inconsistent state (common)?

Comment: @PieterWuille I'm sorry I'm not sure. At the time I looked up the error and found that it likely indicated a "corrupt" blockchain. I did not look into it further and simply used `-reindex` to rebuild and it worked after that. If the common case is an inconsistent state, then I guess that is what I would want to check for.

Comment: @kobejohn: You got any solution for the same because I am facing the same issue and tried for reindexing but after 91% reindex the same error came again

Comment: @Codebrekers Unfortunately I do not. I put that project on hold so I did not work on it. If I were going to, I would probably try an alternate implementation like BitPrim to see if it is more reliable.