# How does bitcoin prevent tampering of blockchain?

Tags: blockchain, full-node

Suppose C is starting bitcoin full node for the first time. C would have to download blockchain from some place. Could not this leave bitcoin susceptible for tampering? If blockchain stored in decentralized way or if blockchain full node constantly check their blockchain, wouldn't this still leave bitcoin susceptible to tempering? For example, if people downloaded blockchain more from a particular group of nodes intending to tamper blockchain, would not blockchain be  compromised? If resolution is done based on bitcoin wealth, this also seems to leave serious issues..

Comment: there are too many questions, and derivated questions... here are more developpers, but: www.bitcoin.org: "the block chain is a shared public ledger on which the entire Bitcoin network relies." Many nodes and miners make sure, that this blockchain get's only updated with validated data. When you download the blockchain to your PC, then data could be tampered, and you'd have  invalid *LOCAL* data. That doesn't harm the shared public ledger (blockchain). recommended reading: https://bitcoin.org/en/developer-guide#block-chain, or the book „Mastering Bitcoin“ by Andreas M. Antonopoulos.

Comment: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/52354/is-there-a-robust-way-to-test-for-a-corrupted-blockchain